# Сбились почти все переводы модераторских действий с сообщением

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, инструменты-модератора

Почти все фразы стали на английском, хотя раньше были на русском:

[image: скриншот]

И полный список непереведённых фраз из этого диалога:

> actions

> add post notice

> convert to wiki

> Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion. This affects the question and all answers.

> move comments to chat

> Creates a new chat room containing all the comments for this post.

> Also delete the moved comments from the post

> purge all comments

> Comments should be purged when they have degraded into pointless bickering and / or noise, and the entire set is unsalvageable. Otherwise, selectively delete comments.

> lock

> Posts should only be locked when something seriously bad is happening. A locked post cannot be changed in any way or voted on, and if the locked post is a question, no new answers can be added.

> convert to comment

> Answers should be converted to comments when they do not attempt to answer the question. A comment should ask for more information or suggest improvements to the post; poor or incomplete answers should simply be downvoted or improved.

> Answers should be converted to an edit of the question when they represent additional/supporting information **by the asker**. The body of the answer is appended to the question.

> Target post URL or ID

> 772600 - The Question

> migrate all comments on this answer as well

> show flag history

> Shows flagging history for this post.

> show review history

> Shows review history for this post.

> show timeline

> Shows the activity on this post.

А также фраз из диалогу у вопроса:

> A protected question prevents answers by anonymous and very new users. Questions should be protected when they are garnering lots of views and newbies are adding "me too!", "thanks!" and possibly even spam non-answers.

> add post notice

> Community wiki questions don't accrue rep and have a lower full editing reputation threshold. Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion. This affects the question and all answers.

> show 1 deleted comments

> Shows all deleted comments for this post.

> Questions should be merged when they are 99% identical and it would be beneficial to have all the answers from multiple duplicate questions in one place. This deletes answers, moves them to the target question, and leaves the current question as a stub with a link to its merge target.

> Master question ID or URL:

> How long would you like the lock to last?

> 1 hour

> permanent

Comment: Что там вообще с сайтовым движком творят? Перенумеровывают строки с нуля?

Comment: @Arhad, мне вот тое интересно...

Comment: Штатный переводчик взял отгул? Раньше такие вопросы решались в фоне.

Comment: @VladD раньше модераторы спокойно сами переводили свою админку, а теперь, видимо, брезгуют.

Comment: @VladD Вы о ком?

Comment: @alexolut, перевёл что ли?

Comment: Не понимаю, о чём Вы... наверное, это афтербан-эффект...

Comment: @alexolut, переводы появились, правда, я не проверял, что все.

Comment: @alexolut: Думаю, что да. В любом случае комментарий не в вашу сторону, а в сторону тех, кто думает, что переводчик будет переводить даже в бане.

Comment: @NickVolynkin мельчают? :)

Comment: @alexolut, переведёно всё кроме слова `actions` в заголовке таба.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я даже в транзификсе не зарегистрирован, чтоб переводить.

Comment: Как оно сейчас?